# Generating random Pools or lakes

Tags: algorithm, procedural-generation, terrain

I have implemented functions that can draw any polygonal shape, however I have been unable to generate a smooth shape that mimics the rounded edges of a lake. I tried generating two circles and joining the edges but there is not enough variation or smoothness to it. Does  anyone have any pointers or ideas that could generate a shape like this?

Comment: I've been looking into bezier curves, it appears that I might be able to generate a lake from that. Anyone have any experience with them on a 2d array?

Answer (score 8):

[alwynd](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/12487/alwynd) mentioned Perlin noise. Here's how I generated the island shapes for the polygon map generator:

1. Generate perlin noise.
2. For each location `(x, y)` in the noise bitmap, compute the distance from the center, normalized so that the bitmap is 2x2: `(dx, dy) = (2 * x / width - 1, 2 * y / height - 1); d = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)`.
3. Location `(x, y)` is part of the island if `noise[x, y] > 0.3 + 0.4*d*d`. This step attempts to make the shape round by cutting off areas that are far from the center.

Islands are a little more ragged than lakes though, so I'm not sure if these shapes will be to your liking. [I've put up a demo of the above algorithm](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/_test/island_shape.swf), with buttons at the bottom to control the two magic numbers. There might be different values of the magic numbers 0.3 and 0.4 that produce shapes you like.

Comment: Your work is a major inspiration, Amit. +10k if I could, for the 5 years or so of wonder and enjoyment I've gotten out of reading your blog.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Perlin Noise algorithm to generate the lakes for you, if you are using a top down view (polygon shape, sounds like you are), this guy from Stanford did just that.

http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/

Comment: "That guy from Stanford" is also a user on this site, FYI.

Comment: who isn't? =) I might start off from some noise (perlin, fractal), but blur the results for less "jaggy" results. Great article, btw - love how he does the rivers.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to start with a basic polygon, maybe your 2 circles approach.

Firstly offset all points randomly, so doesn't look too much like a circle, then for every edge, split it in 2 and offset the middle point by some small random amount. Keep doing this until you have the required detail.
This is similar to what's done when generating forks of lightning.